# find three objects in a relationship with fewer joins

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm doing an SQL excerise and determined a solution however I feel like the joining of 4 tables in my solution is brute force way to do what I did.

I have the following tables:

**`Highschooler ( ID, name, grade )`**

**`Friend ( ID1, ID2 )`** ID1 is a mutual friend of ID2 => if `[ID1, ID2]` exists within `Friend`, then so must `[ID2, ID1]`

**`Likes ( ID1, ID2 )`** ID1 is attracted to ID2

The question was:

> For each student A who likes a student B where the two are not friends, find if they have a friend C in common (who can introduce them!). For all such trios, return the name and grade of A, B, and C.

And my solution:

```
Select  H1.name, H1.grade, H2.name, H2.grade, H3.name, H3.grade
FROM    Highschooler H1, Highschooler H2, Highschooler H3,

        -- Following table contains each trio of A, B, C
        (Select L.ID1 as ID1, L.ID2 as ID2, F.ID2 as ID3
        FROM (SELECT * FROM Likes EXCEPT SELECT * FROM Friend) as L, Friend as F
        WHERE   L.ID1 = F.ID1 AND -- Found a potential friend C of A
                F.ID2 in (SELECT ID2 FROM Friend WHERE Friend.ID1 = L.ID2)) -- Does potential C appear in list of B's friends?

WHERE   H1.ID = ID1 and H2.ID = ID2 and H3.ID = ID3
```

I feel like the `Highschooler H1, Highschooler H2, Highschooler H3` statement is my 'brute-forcing'.

The `SELECT` statement within the first `FROM` correctly finds the `[A.ID, B.ID, C.ID]` trios whilst the rest of the statement just fetches the names and grades responding to those IDs.

Is there a better way to do this fetching than the 4-way join I have done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should give the same result, but using a slightly different syntax. In the end you'll need to join in Highschooler three times as you need the name and grade for three different persons - not much to do about that.

```
select 
    liker.name, liker.grade, 
    liked.name, liked.grade, 
    common_friend.name, common_friend.grade
from likes l 

-- student1 who likes
join Highschooler liker on liker.ID = l.ID1 

-- student2 who is liked
join Highschooler liked on liked.ID = l.ID2 

-- friends on student1
join Friend f on l.ID1 = f.ID1 
            -- that are in student2s friends
             and f.ID2 in (select id1 from friend where id2 = l.ID2) 
-- the common friend
join Highschooler common_friend on common_friend.ID = f.ID2 

-- student1 and student2 can't be friends
where not exists (select 1 from Friend where ID1 = l.ID1 and id2 = l.ID2)
```

Comment: That looks very neat and tidy :) I will try do as much as I can in this format because I really like it! Now that I think about it I should have submitted this Q to code review instead, argh